# ResourceNotFoundException ListViewAdapter

Tags: java, android

I made a constructor `DataPembeli`for list view item then make the custom List View Adapter `DataPembeliListAdapter`
and used the constructor like this:

```
txtid.setText(dataPembeliItems.get(position).getId()); // THIS IS THE ERROR LINE  
txtket1.setText(dataPembeliItems.get(position).getNama());
txtket2.setText(dataPembeliItems.get(position).getAlamat());
txtket3.setText(dataPembeliItems.get(position).getNohp());
```

In the `DataPembeliFragment` class I've used it like this:

```
public class DataPembeliFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listPembeli;
private ImageButton btnTambah;

// slide data items
private int[] idDataPembeli;
private String[] namaDataPembeli, alamatDataPembeli, noHpDataPembeli;

private ArrayList<DataPembeli> dataPembeliItems;
private DataPembeliListAdapter adapter;

public DataPembeliFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_pembeli, container, false);

    listPembeli = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_sliderdata);
    btnTambah = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTambah);
    btnTambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showEditDialog();
        }
    });

    dataPembeliItems = new ArrayList<DataPembeli>();
    idDataPembeli = new int[10];
    namaDataPembeli = new String[10];
    alamatDataPembeli = new String[10];
    noHpDataPembeli = new String[10];

    idDataPembeli[0]    = 1;
    namaDataPembeli[0]  = "ryno";
    alamatDataPembeli[0]= "padang";
    noHpDataPembeli[0]  = "0812874512";

    dataPembeliItems.add(new DataPembeli(idDataPembeli[0], namaDataPembeli[0], alamatDataPembeli[0], noHpDataPembeli[0]));

    idDataPembeli[1]    = 2;
    namaDataPembeli[1]  = "yezu";
    alamatDataPembeli[1]= "padang";
    noHpDataPembeli[1]  = "0819232211";

    dataPembeliItems.add(new DataPembeli(idDataPembeli[1], namaDataPembeli[1], alamatDataPembeli[1], noHpDataPembeli[1]));

    idDataPembeli[2]    = 3;
    namaDataPembeli[2]  = "test";
    alamatDataPembeli[2]= "padangs";
    noHpDataPembeli[2]  = "0819232xx";

    dataPembeliItems.add(new DataPembeli(idDataPembeli[2], namaDataPembeli[2], alamatDataPembeli[2], noHpDataPembeli[2]));

    listPembeli.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    adapter = new DataPembeliListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),dataPembeliItems);
    listPembeli.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

When I call the Fragment I got `ResourceNotFoundException` in the logcat at DataPembeliAdapter on the line that I marked above.(at comment "//THIS IS THE ERROR LINE")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText` method needs `String` argument to display, but you are placing `int` value, so he is trying to get string from resource. You just need `txtid.setText(Integer.toString(dataPembeliItems.get(position).getId()))`.

Comment: thanks, i dont know that settext function is using Charsquence